# Can't call Invoke()

Tags: c#, reflection, system.reflection

I'm trying to call `Invoke()` but it always throws:

> Object does not match target type

I'm not sure what to pass as first parameter - presuming that this is the issue - and I have tried many things with no luck. Below goes my code:

```
var method = typeof(IBaseRepository<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(Domain.Model.Basic.City))
                 .GetMethod("Get", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

var entityData = method.Invoke(??, new[] { (object)id });
```

The `BaseRepository` is:

```
public class BaseRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T>
{
    public virtual T Get(object id) { }
}
```

`City` class is:

```
public class City : Entity
```

And `Entity` is an abstract class:

```
public abstract class Entity
```

As first Invoke's parameter I have tried using an instance of `City` - which should be the right case - and instance of `Entity` and other things I was sure would not work actually.

Comment: where you have `??` you need to pass in an instance of your repository.

Comment: Specifically, an instance of something that implements  `IBaseRepository<Domain.Model.Basic.City>`

Comment: according to your class definitions, that would have to be a `new BaseRepository<City>()`, since the first argument of `Invoke` is documented as "The object on which to invoke the method or constructor"

Comment: Thank you guys for all suggestions, already looking into each one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//you are missing this part  (FYI, this won't work if BaseRepo<T> is abstract)
var repoType = typeof(BaseRepository<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(City));
var repo = repoType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(null);

int id = 0; //whatever your id is...

var method = typeof(IBaseRepository<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(City))
                .GetMethod("Get", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
var entityData = (Entity)method.Invoke(repo, new[] { (object)id }) ;
```

Comment: Yeah it works. The only difference in my final solution was on `repo` part, which I have to *resolve* with my depency injector, but I managed it to work!! Your tips helped, thanks a lot.

Comment: Somebody is really mad about this question and is downvoting for free..

Comment: Your better option would be to put another interface that doesn't care about the generic type parameter and just put that on your repos... Then you don't need reflection.